# How to set Applitools environment variable in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, applitools

I'm trying to set up and run eyes-storybook for my Next.js project but running into this error;

Environment variable APPLITOOLS_API_KEY is not set.
To fix:

1. Register for Applitools developer account at [www.applitools.com/devreg](http://www.applitools.com/devreg)
2. Get API key from menu
3. Set APPLITOOLS_API_KEY environment variable
   Mac/Linux: export APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=Your_API_Key_Here
   Windows: set APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=Your_API_Key_Here

I already have completed steps 1 & 2. I have tried running set APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=Your_API_Key_Here (with my API key of course) within the terminal while in the project directory on VScode but to no avail. I have also tried setting the variable through command prompt and still no luck.

Where am I supposed to run "set APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=Your_API_Key_Here"? I am on windows and the Applitools docs say "set" is the correct command for windows, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: also I am wondering if APPLITOOLS_API_KEY=Your_API_Key_Here should have quotes? for example APPLITOOLS_API_KEY="Your_API_Key_Here"?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add some explanation or code instead of using comments as you did.